# Visual studio load test - Automated report generation

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

I am working with Visual studio Load test. I want to prepare Excel report after successful Load test. I want to trigger a Exe or create custom C# class inside the Load test solution for the report generation. But for both i need the test ending event. Is there anyway to find out Report completion?

Thanks in advance,
Subbiah K

Answer (score 0):

A load test plugin can run at the end of the test. Its documentation is not clear on whether that means after the tests have executed or after all the results have been saved. I am not aware of any way of "triggering" the Excel report generation by program.

If you run the load test by using `mstest.exe` or a similar program then you can follow that by a command by another that you write to do the reporting you require.

The ".testsettings" file has an option for a command (batch or exe etc) to be run after a test completes. I have not tried using it with a load test but it may provide a place to call your reporting program.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have implemented LoadtestPlugin and creating excel using interop assemblies in the LoadTestFinished event.  But the issue is the results are posted to the DB after the LoadTestFinished event,  Is there any way to get the transaction summary inside loadtest plugin object?